# PHP How do I reduce CPU usage?

Tags: php

My server runs PHP.

What are main things that spike up CPU usage? Garbage Collection? Any tips for reducing CPU usage?

I got rid of all File I/O using RAM, so that is no a problem.

Sometimes my CPU usage goes up to 40%, and I want to try to reduce that to 20%.

There is not much documentation online on what causes huge spikes, what I should avoid, etc. Anyone have any input?